# I'm looking to print the length of the longest and shortest words but am unsure where I'm going wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import string
a = input("Input a string ")
aSplit = a.split()
for aString in aSplit:
    print (aString)
sLen =(len(aString))

def minmax(sLen):
    if len(1) == 0 : return None
    smallest = largest = 1[0]
    for n in 1 :
        if n < smallest : smallest = n
        elif n > largest : largest = n
    return (smallest, largest)
print (minmax, sLen)
```

What I am currently getting as my print result for minmax:

```
function ex4. locals .minmax at 0x03FFD1E0 6
```

I'm looking to make it prettier and print the minimum value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with your code but the main problem is how you are calling the function. You should be calling it like `print(minmax(sLen))`, and even then you wouldn't be getting the results you expect because `sLen` represents the length of the last element in your `aSplit` list.

To get the length of the longest and shortest words from a string, as per your question, you can use the code below.

```
def minmax(my_string):
    string_list = my_string.split() # Split string into list
    sorted_list = sorted(map(len, string_list)) # Apply len() to all elements of list and sort
    output = (sorted_list[0], sorted_list[-1]) # Use list indexing to get first and last element of list
    return output
```